School of thought VS Notion
Notion: an idea, a belief or an understanding of something
School of thought: a set of ideas or opinions that a group of people share about a matter

Given the increasing rates of deaths caused by traffic accidents, many people believe that only by implementing stricter traffic laws can the safety of our roads be improved. However, in this essay, I will challenge this _________.

By the definitions of the word and the phrase above, I feel that notion is better here because there is only one belief I want to challenge. However, I wonder if the difference between these two is only the number of ideas or if there is some other factor contributing to one's word choice in this case.
So, how are they different? Is "school of thought" equally good here?

Voting to close as the variety of answers provided make it as clear as day that the answer is a matter of opinion, not grammar. The OP can make whatever choice they want, and it's down to their discretion. Continual lengthy answers saying 'I prefer this one because ...' are not helpful to learners.

A (metaphoric) school of thought is a lot more substantial than a notion, because it implies many other (by implication, educated) people having the same idea(s).
To have a "notion" about something can be a very ephemeral (short-lived) process, sometimes just briefly considering an idea before discarding it as worthless.
Perhaps the OP should consider (also metaphoric, but in a very different way)...

train of thought


So to sum up, notion is not good because it's not substantial enough, and I have two good choices here, which are train of thought and school of thought, but the former is better?

If I understand correctly, could you expand on how train of thought is better than school of thought?

I just did. What don't you understand?

I'd written the first comment before you edited your answer. So, I guess now the only question left is my second comment. You haven't said clearly how they are different, and why I should consider "train of thought".

In your context, I'd say "school of thought" is a somewhat "lofty" expression. You might get away with it, but personally I don't think it's worth getting bogged down in literary or idiomatic terminology in your exact context. Just in this essay, I will challenge this idea (or this thinking, if you want to "elevate" the "Aunt Sally" you intend to demolish).

...note that since the reality is traffic fatalities are in fact already decreasing, anyone who thinks we need stricter traffic laws to turn things around from an increase to a decrease clearly isn't very well educated as regards the specific issue here. Imho that's one more reason not to dignify such people as belonging to a school of thought. They're more like "unthinking ideologues".

Actually, it doesn't matter what's happening out there because it's an English test. I just need to state my opinion about what the question says. If the test assumes that there are many people who believe so, then that's the case. That's why they never inform us of the setting. There mightn't be many people holding such a belief, but in the essay, we assume that there're a large enough number of them and we have to give our opinion about whether we agree with them or not.

Yes, I understand If the test assumes that there are many people who believe so, then that's the case. But if the test asks you to choose between school and train then it becomes relevant whether those "many people" should be accorded the "status, credibility" of belonging to a school of thought. No matter how many half-wits believe the earth is flat, or the moon landings were fake, you wouldn't normally accord them the dignity of saying they belong to a "school of thought". Mental activity at that level barely deserves to be called "thought", let alone "a school"!

Also note definition II.8.c in the full OED for notion: colloquial (now chiefly Irish English). In plural. Pretensions, affectations; ambitions or desires beyond what might be expected of one's social position, class, community, etc. Often in to get (also have) notions. A "school of thought" is very upmarket, but a "notion" is often extremely "downmarket" (and/or transitory - another OED definition has notion = whim).

Yes, the "number of ideas" matters, but so does the number of people. You've found a situation in which either could work, but we could imagine some that could use only one.
If I write an essay giving my personal opinion, perhaps one that only I think, and you want to refute it, it can hardly be called a "school of thought" because it's supported by just one person. Just as a "school of fish" is a group, notice that the dictionary definition you gave includes "group of people." It suggests models in which one teacher has a number of followers, like ancient Greek philosophers. Thus the "Socratic school of thought" could be "the position of Socrates, his immediate disciples, and those who have agreed with them over time."
Or, to go the other way, a "notion" is generally one discrete idea. But a "school of thought" could encompass an overarching philosophy that has many components that work together.

Cobra Kai says the strong must prey on the weak. It says to strike first and show no mercy. It says that winning matters above all else. It says that you must do whatever it takes to win, even if that means cheating. I challenge that school of thought.

I think really one could use "notion" there since all these ideas are part of a very coherent whole, but "school of thought" is a better choice (and, even, a literal choice for a dojo!).

@everyone Wow, opinions on this question differ widely among people. I've given a clearer context below FF's answer. I hope to receive a more unanimous answer if that's possible.

In this case, notion is the better choice because

You are arguing against the idea, therefore you want to cast doubt on this assertion.
It is easier to challenge a single person's experience than a group consensus.


It can be either one depending on what you want to say. It depends on how you define it based on those dictionary definitions.
Howver, "train of thought" does not work as a train of thought is usually more momentary.  Your shouting has interrupted my train of thought.
Personally, I don't think that implementing stricter laws for something is a "notion".

"I don't think that implementing stricter laws for something is a "notion"" => Yeah I mean I challenge the belief that implementing stricter...

@AnIELTSLearner You have my answer.
